# socket_read зависает в PHP

Tags: php, сокет, tcp-ip

Проблема заключается в следующем, после записи данных в сокет, функция socket_read пытается считать данные и зависает.
Точнее зависанием это трудно назвать, скорее она находится в бесконечном ожидании.
Даже если ограничить время set_time_limit(3), то через 3 секунды скрипт не вырубается.

Запись в сокет проходит нормально, возвращает количество байт.

Вот код. Адрес и порт сервера разумеется в тайне. Подскажите, все ли верно в коде?

```
$requestXml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><test><query></query></test>';



// Подключение к сокету
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if(!socket_connect($socket, "000.000.000.000", 11111))
    die('Socket connect error: ' . socket_last_error());

$size = socket_write($socket, $requestXml, 100);
if(!$size)
    die('Socket send error: ' . socket_last_error());

$responseHeaders = socket_read($socket, 1, PHP_NORMAL_READ);

var_dump($responseHeaders);
```

Есть программа на Java, которая выполняет те же действия с теми же данными, она получает данные нормально.

Comment: да, такое бывает, сервер может не послать конец ответа и может не закрывать соединение. Я решал такую проблему своим лимитом времени на получение именно данных

Answer (score 1):

Как и писал в комментарии, я столкнулся с похожей ситуацией, когда сервер мог не закрыть соединение, а так же может не отдавать конец строки. Я решил такую проблему своим таймаутом именно на получение данных. Вот часть кода:

```
class TcpClient {
    // ...
    private $_tryEof = 0;
    private $_maxTryEof = 20;
    private $_lastBufSize = 0;
    // ...
    private function _connect()
    {
        $this->_handler = stream_socket_client($this->_remoteSocket, $this->_errNo, $this->_errStr, $this->_timeout);
        // ...
    }
    private function _feof($eofStr)
        {
            $bufSize = strlen($this->buf);
            if ($this->_lastBufSize === $bufSize) {
                $this->_tryEof++;
                if ($this->_tryEof > $this->_maxTryEof) {
                    $this->_disconnect();
                }
            }
        }else{
            $this->_tryEof = 0;
        }
        $this->_lastBufSize = $bufSize;
        $result = strpos($this->_buf, $eofStr);

        return $result;
    }

    private function _read()
    {
        $this->_buf = '';
        $endResponse = "</return>";
        while (!$this->_feof($endResponse)) {
            $buf = fread($this->_handler, 10240);
            $this->_buf .= $buf;
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Нет, у меня проблема совсем в другом. В php функция socket_read вообще не считывает ни одного байта. Но тот же запрос на Java отлично работает.